# Awesome WM: Rearrange windows without changing layout

Tags: layout, lua, awesome-wm

I'm entirely new to Awesome and Lua, but what I would like to achieve is to cycle through different arrangements of my windows within the same window-layout. Maybe I didn't use the correct search terms, but a simple Google search didn't yield anything helpful, and I don't want to take the time to study the Lua API to do it myself from scratch.

Say I have 3 tiles arranged like this in some arbitrary order:

```
+------+-------+
|      |       |
|      |       |
+------+       |
|      |       |
|      |       |
+------+-------+
```

Now I want to easily make the window that I'm focussing on appear in the big right-hand tile without cycling through all the different layouts using Super-Space.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the focused window to become the master window - correct? If so, you may want to have a look here: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome_3.x#Window_manager_control.
It says Mod4+control+return swaps focused client with master - which, as far as I can tell, is what you want to achieve (Mod4 is the super key).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't figure this out myself. It's not entirely what I had in mind, but it works just as well! Hadn't noticed the concept of Master-windows yet. Thanks!

Comment: Frustratingly this doesn't appear to work with Firefox. Using a spiral layout it works with other open programs just not the browser. Can anyone shed any light as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

Despite tiling wm does not imply mouse using, it still work. You can simply drag and drop window on wanted place when holding Mod4 key.

Comment: Not very practical on a laptop. The whole reason for using awesome is to have as much control as possible using only my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use a `mod4/super` key with a `shift key` plus `k` to advance backward with a selected window on a viewport, and `mod4+shift+j` to advance forward with a selected window on the viewport.